# Can a person travel after being deported from Canada for money laundering?

Tags: deportation

Can a person from India, deported from Canada for money laundering, travel or get visa after being deported from Canada?

Comment: This question is way too broad. It depends on the country you're trying to go to.

Comment: What is your citizenship? Where do you want to travel to?

Answer (score 7):

The visa application forms for many countries will ask if the visitor has ever been deported, removed, denied entry, or denied a visa. From now on that person will have to answer "yes" to the question.

Usually this will not result in an *automatic* refusal, but the application and the personal circumstances of the applicant will be considered more carefully.

It would be possible to lie in the form, but **if** the other country finds out, they will probably deny the visa because of the lie even if they would have granted it otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Money laundering is a serious criminal offence (according the IRPA this includes any offense punishable by a maximum of at least 10 years imprisonment). If you were deported--as opposed to being excluded--you would require an ARC to return to Canada.

However, your criminality is a bigger issue. Depending on your charge, conviction and sentence you could be automatically barred from many countries for many years.

Some countries such as the Schengen countries don't ask applicants for their criminal history. It is also highly unlikely they will find out on their own. If you are otherwise eligible,you could try your luck there. There are also less developed countries which you could travel to.